# In an optimization, what constraints can I use to ensure that if one variable is positive, a separate variable is a specific value

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Let's imagine a linear program where I have 3 assets, a b c, with inventory of 10, 20, and 30.

How would I design a constraint that says if ANY amount of asset 3 is sold, all of asset C must be sold. (so if a > 0, c = 30). However, c can be sold in any amount if a is not sold (c < 30, a = 0)

Comment: Something like $a(30-c)=0$ would help, but I don't know if this is still a linear program.

Comment: You can't do this in linear programming (the feasible set is nonconvex), but you can do it using integer linear programming.

Answer (score 1):

Binary conditions like this are nonlinear.

What you have is two feasible regions, one with $a=0$ and $c$ arbitrary, and another with $c=30$ and $a$ arbitrary.  Their union is no longer a region that can be handled with standard LP methods.

Answer (score 1):

Basically we have: $c=30$ or $a=0$.

$$\begin{align} &c \ge 30\delta \\ 
                & a \le 10\delta \\ 
                & a \in [0,10]  \\
                &  c \in [0,30] \\
                & \delta \in \{0,1\} \end{align}$$